# CAN communication with the SM470R1B1M-HT microcontroller

Tags: microcontroller, arm, can, texas-instruments, arm7

I bought the IAR Kickstarter kit to work with the [SM470R1B1M-HT](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/sm470r1b1m-ht.pdf) ([Texas Instruments](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Texas_Instruments)) microcontroller. I would like to implement CAN communication between the microcontroller and a PC. I need to send commands from the PC and get some response from the controller.

I haven't seen any examples with CAN communication. How do I implement CAN communication in this microcontroller? Are there any tools which generate automatic code for CAN communication?

[CAN document for SM470R1B1M-HT](http://www.ti.com/lit/ug/spnu197e/spnu197e.pdf).

Comment: Have you made any progress here? Are there any other things that you might need help with aside from being given source code?

Answer (score 2):

As far as tools go, no you are not likely to find anything. Luckily the CAN protocol is relatively simple and you can gather a lot of information through your good friends at google.

ex: First 3 links when googling CAN Protocol:

http://www.ni.com/white-paper/2732/en/

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CAN_bus

http://www.ti.com/lit/an/sloa101a/sloa101a.pdf‎

One thing that you will need if you are trying to implement CAN comms is what is called a CAN transceiver. Check out the MCP2551 IC, I have had luck with it in the past (provided that your MCU has 5V IO levels).

3.3V CAN Transciever

http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/sn65hvd233-ht.pdf‎

MCP 2551

http://www.microchip.com/MCP2551‎

In order to communicate with the PC you will need some kind of interface that will connect to your PC anc interpret the CAN messages. There are multiple ways that this can be done. There are USB transcievers as you see here: [http://www.amazon.com/USB-CAN-Converter-Adapter-Support-64-bit/dp/B009SG6OL6](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B009SG6OL6)

There are also CAN cards that will attach to your PCI-X slots on your motherboard.

In regards to existing examples, look for examples that are not specific to your platform. While the implementation may be slightly different, the concept and protocols are the same.

Also...it looks like most of the information that you would need is provided in the links that you posted. Take your time, read through the datasheets and try to write some simple CAN communications that you can debug with a scope or better yet, logic probe!

If there is anything else that needs to be added to make his as an accepted answer, please let me know!

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I had CANUSB tool to communicate with PC but what i need basically is some example codes and i have to use only this controller because of high temp. I had already gone through the links you provided and as well i provided.Anyway thanks for your suggestion i will try my best.

Comment: As far as finding example code, it is tough to do with obscure micrcontrollers. Your best off to just start with simple code and work your way forward from there. Don't expect to find nice examples like you would for other platforms. It will make your life writing embedded software much easier